# RowDataBound : Getting value from dataTable ! Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying in RowDataBound event to get a value from dataTable for the current editing row:
Here's my code:

```
string KK = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name");
if ( KK == "John" )
{
//execute code
}
```

ERROR : Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'. at the first line ( the one with String KK...)

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) of the `GridViewRow` instead of `DataBinder.Eval` to get the underlying datasource:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit))
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        String name = row.Field<String>("Name");
        // String is a reference type, so you just need to compare with null
        if(name != null){/* do something */}
    }
}
```

The [`Field` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) also supports nullable types.

Answer (score 1):

check for DBNull.Value and retrieve your data if not DBNull.Value

Answer (score 1):

DBNull indicates that the value is a null value in 
the DB, which indicates the absence of a value. You might want to check 
that the query is returning valid data. If it is, you need to find a value 
to use when the item in the list is null.

Try this:

```
string KK = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name").GetType() == typeof(System.DBNull) ? "" : (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "IsNull"-method to properly check for null values, before you can try to retrieve it.

Comment: well the thing is that , the column cells values will never be empty because the user can't edit them/

Answer (score 0):

You should grab the `DataRow` and work off of that:

```
var row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow;
if (row != null)
{
    //for strings this will work fine
    var name = row.Field<string>("Name");

    //for other types use the IsNull function to check for DBNull
    if (!row.IsNull("SomeDecimalValue"))
        var value = row.Field<decimal>("SomeDecimalValue");
}
```

**EDIT** Another option is to use a nullable type when there's a chance that a value is `null` or `DBNull`:

```
var value = row.Field<decimal?>("SomeDecimalValue");
if (value.HasValue)
{

}
```